# Jquery drop down list applies space to left

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good Day

I have a dynamically populated drop down list  with list options .
Problem is that when I choose and option from the list, it applies a spacing ( ) to the left of the text as it would appear in the tree stucture

Now the list is styled in a tree stucture and is called from another loation on the server. I cannot change the spacing in that. (since t forms the tree structure effect)

Look at my code below:

HTML

```
<select id="AreaTreeSelect" data-bind="value: RiskAssessment.AreaId"></select>
```

Jquery

```
               $.ajax({
                    url: "API/DataHandler.ashx?method=getareatree",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        for (var i in result) {
                            var obj = result[i];

                            $("#AreaTreeSelect").append("<option value=\"" + obj.Id + "\">" + obj.Name + "</option>");

                        }
                    }
                });
```

This is how it populates in the browser:

```
<select id="AreaTreeSelect" data-bind="value: RiskAssessment.AreaId">
<option value="156">Ferrometals</option>
<option value="158">&nbsp;&nbsp;Admin &amp; Finance</option>
<option value="169">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Warehousing</option>
<option value="170">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Procurement</option>
<option value="171">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Acounting</option>
<option value="855">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Information Technology</option>
<option value="159">&nbsp;&nbsp;HR</option>
</select>
```

etc...

How do I remove the space when the **option is selected** an displayed in the select box?

Comment: $.trim(obj.Name) ... i think it solves your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be worth trying:

```
$('#AreaTreeSelect').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option.trimmed').each(function(){
        var padding = '';
        for(var i=0; i<$(this).data('numSpaces'); i++){
            padding += String.fromCharCode(160);
        }
        $(this).text(padding + $(this).text());
    })
    .removeClass('trimmed');
    var selOpt = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var numSpaces = selOpt.text().replace(/^(\s*).*/, '$1').length;
    selOpt
        .data('numSpaces', numSpaces)
        .text(selOpt.text().replace(/^\s*/g, ''))
        .addClass('trimmed');
});
```

The idea is that it removes all &nbsp; from the currently selected option, but remembers how much padding there was and restores the padding when another option is selected.

Obviously, you could store the actual sequence of &nbsp; instead of the number of them, and get rid of a few lines of code.

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aKGac/1/

The obvious downside with this solution is that the currently selected option will appear in the list without any indentation when it is expanded:

[image: No indentation on selected option]

Comment: Thank you fpr your answer. However, does not work and gives debugging issues

Comment: I still believe the code would achieve what you want. Do the errors seem hard to overcome?

Comment: I created a fiddle, corrected the code and updated my answer. I have to admit though that the solution is not perfect, as it has one pretty serious flaw that is hard to overcome.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. What exactly is the flaw? I will run it in Visual Studio, hopefully it doesn't scorn...

Comment: I mean the issue with the currently selected option not being indented in the list. I added a screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me BUT the debugger tells me the following: 
Unhandled exception at line 570, column 29 in http://localhost:49693/Secure/RiskAssessmentItem.aspx?assessmentno=0

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I see. Yeah, there was a bug when selecting the option without any leading spaces. I also found another problem, but have fixed both and updated fiddle and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this it trim the spaces...

```
$("#AreaTreeSelect").append("<option value=\"" + obj.Id + "\">" + $.trim(obj.Name) + "</option>");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work. It still applies the spacing...Any other suggestions?